# Euler’s theorem and probabilities (Word problem)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Lily is buying a lottery ticket that requires a $4$-digit number. She decides to choose a number by taking a random $2$ digit integer $n$, and using the number $7^n \text{ (mod 10000) }$ as the lottery number. What is the probability that the sum of the last two digits of her ticket number sum to $7$?

We have the totient $\phi(10000) = 4000$. From this we could get that $7^{4000} \equiv 1 \text{ (mod 10000)}.$ From here on I’m not sure how to proceed. Is it the case here that we want to find $n$ that would satisfy for example $7^{n} \equiv 25\text{ (mod 10000)},$ since $2+5=7$? If so couldn’t I just multiply the expression $7^{4000} \equiv 1 \text{ (mod 10000)}$ by $25$ and get that $25\cdot7^{4000} \equiv 25 \text{ (mod 10000)} \Rightarrow$ $25^1 \equiv 25 \text{ (mod 10000)}?$ (this is just me thinking out loud... doesn’t seem to be going in the right direction). What am I missing?

Comment: Hint : The last two digits of $7^n mod 10000$ are the same as the last two digits of simply $7^n$, additionally, we have $ord_7(100)=4$

Comment: I’m not familiar with the notation $ord_7(100) = 4$. Could you elaborate on what does it represent?

Comment: The order $ord_7(100)$ is the smallest positive integer $m$ with $7^m\equiv 1\mod 100$. By the way, is this an ongoing contest ?

Comment: Ah alright thanks! And nope it’s a problem I found online, seems to be from some old high school contest.